# Transaction is rolled back after commit?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm experiencing some problems that look a LOT like a transaction in a stored procedure has been rolled back, even though I'm fairly certain that it was committed, since the output variable isn't set until after the commit, and the user gets the value of the output variable (I know, because they print it out and I also set up a log table where i input the value of the output variable).
In theory someone COULD manually delete and update the data such that it would look like a rollback, but it is extremely unlikely.

So, I'm hoping someone can spot some kind of structural mistake in my stored procedure. Meet BOB:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[BOB] (@output_id int OUTPUT, @output_msg varchar(255) OUTPUT)
as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @record_id int

SET @output_id = 1

-- some preliminary if-statements that doesn't alter any data, but might do a RETURN

SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
    --insert into table A

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    --update table B

    DECLARE csr cursor local FOR 
        SELECT [some stuff] and record_id
        FROM temp_table_that_is_not_actually_a_temporary_table
    open csr

    fetch next from csr into [some variables], @record_id
    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin   
        --check type of item + if valid
        IF (something)
        BEGIN
            SET SOME VARIABLE
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            SET @output_msg = 'item does not exist'
            SET @output_id = 0
            RETURN
        END

        --update table C

        --update table D

        --insert into table E

        --execute some other stored procedure (without transactions)

        if (something)
        begin
            --insert into table F

            --update table C again      
        end

        DELETE FROM temp_table_that_is_not_actually_a_temporary_table WHERE record_id=@record_id

        fetch next from csr into [some variables], @record_id
    end
    close csr
    deallocate csr

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    SET @output_msg = 'ok'
    SET @output_id = @id
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SET @output_msg = 'transaction failed !'
    SET @output_id = 0
    INSERT INTO errors (record_time, sp_name, sp_msg, error_msg)
    VALUES (getdate(), 'BOB', @output_msg, error_message())
END CATCH

RETURN
END
```

I know, my user gets an @output_id that is the SCOPE_IDENTITY() and he also gets an @output_msg that says 'ok'. Is there ANY way he can get those outputs without the transaction getting committed?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything in your procedure that would cause the behavior you say is happening. I would however suggest that using a cursor like this is not the most efficient way of doing this type of thing. It would be better from a number of perspectives to change this into a set based approach instead of RBAR.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't believe there is really a set based approach that would work in this case. Anyway, most of the time the "temp" table contains less than five rows, so it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: I would at least suggest using an actual temp table instead of a persistent table acting like a temp table. That is problematic when concurrency comes into play.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible without rewriting a large chunk of the system :/

Comment: Is it possible that something weird can happen with the transactions if several users are calling the procedure at the same time while using the same user credentials?

Comment: It isn't the transactions that get screwy it is the nonTemp table pretending to be a temp table. Whose data is really in there when multiple people are running this at the same time?

Comment: I'm not going to pretend this is an optimal setup, but what you can't see in my simplified version of this procedure is that it is called with several variables that decide the identity of the caller, which also links it together with the rows of the wannabe temp table that belong to that caller.
Even though I agree this setup with a non-temp temp-table is.. well, not optimal, I'm fairly certain this is not the actual issue. But thank you for your feedback, I am considering the system rewrite :/

Comment: Don't know if this is still an issue but the most obvious way this could be problematic is if it's called when a transaction is already active. SQL Server doesn't really support nested transactions and all that commit does for a "nested" transaction is decrement the transaction count.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right, obviously. But let's say I know for sure that what is calling the procedure is not transactional. Can it be problematic just because some other transaction is running in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You know the problem is that transaction dose NOT support rollback on variables because there is no data change inside database. Either commit or rollback of the transactions ONLY make difference on those database objects (tables, temp table, etc.), NOT THE VARIABLES (including table variables).

--**EDIT**

```
declare @v1 int = 0, @v2 int = 0, @v3 int = 0

set @v2 = 1

begin tran
set @v1 = 1
commit tran

begin tran
set @v3 = 1
rollback tran

select @v1 as v1, @v2 as v2, @v3 as v3
```

**RESULT is as follows**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I hadn't actually thought about this.
However, the value of the variable isn't set until after commit.
Also, what I didn't mention in my question, is that after returning the @output_id to the user, the user fetches data from the table based on the id - which it does succesfully. But still, some time after, the data isn't there.

Comment: When the value of variable is set depends on the query, not the transaction commit or rollback. I added some query and result to show it to you. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean.
But in my case it's more like this:
declare @v int;
begin tran;
-- add row to table;
commit tran;
set @v = 1;

Comment: Anyway - I really appreciate your response, because this is important and I hadn't thought about it until now. However, it doesn't resolve my issue. But it might still help me out, so I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: In this case, I suppose the @v is a some kind of flag to show whether the insertion is done or not. Because you cannot roll back the variable's value. you can setup a column within the table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never used transactions in stored procedures, especially when they are used simultaniously by many people. I seriously avoid cursors as well.

I think I would go with passing the involved rows of temp_table_that_is_not_actually_a_temporary_table into a real temp table and then go with an if statement for all rows together. That's so simple in tsql:

select (data) into #temp from (normal_table) where (conditions).

What's the point of checking each row, doing the job and then rollback the whole thing if say the last row doesn't meet the condition? Do the check for all of them at once, do the job for all of them at once. That's what sql is all about.

Comment: I actually already did alter the procedure such that it passes the rows to a real temp table. It didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Regarding the cursor: it would be extremely complicated code, if I had to do it without the cursor. There are seriously many checks for all kinds of weird stuff all depending on the type of item. I see your point with checking everything first, but I don't think it makes sense in this case, and I don't see how it's relevant to the issue,
Regarding transactions: I don't understand why you would just avoid it. How do you make sure then that you don't get half "transactions"? (It is in fact essential to this system that it either happens or doesn't. Anything in between is not allowed.)

Comment: It's difficult to understand what exactly is your need from an abstract example. I wouldn't expect an OLTP database to need so many updates for a single transaction. However, if you can work asynchronously there's a better way to do it. Build an intermediate table and instead of updating all those tables, feed the transaction data in the intermediate. Add a status column "Status". Have a process parsing this table regularly and executing the transactions with status null. Once each transaction is done, update status to complete or failed.

Comment: Thus you will create a transaction queue. You will have your transactions happening one after the other, no nested transactions needed ;)